# Remove transparent pixels from selection in GIMP (Script-Fu)

Tags: colors, alpha, gimp, script-fu

I'm writing a script for GIMP and I'm stuck on this.

I want to deselect transparent pixels from user selection.

GIMP doesn't take RGBA values, so I can't just write:

```
(gimp-image-select-color inImage CHANNEL-OP-SUBTRACT inLayer '(0 0 0 0))
```

There is an error, because a color list can't have 4 elements.

How can I subtract alpha channel transparency from current selection?
It is possible with GIMP UI (selected subtract switch in Select by Color Tool). I wanna achieve the same effect with script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intersect your selection with a selection made from the non-transparent pixels, in other words:

- Save the selection mask
- Alpha to selection
- Invert selection
- Intersect with saved selection mask

(or vice-versa)